# Shiny: Gauge from flexdashboard in Shiny App

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard, flexdashboard

Is it possible to embed the gauge from `flexdashboard` (picture below) in `Shiny` App (`shinydashboard` or `shiny`)?

[image]

The example code within a `Shiny flexdashboard` from the `flexdashboard` [website](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/using.html#components):

````
```{r}
renderGauge({
  rate <- computeContactRate(input$region)
  gauge(rate, min = 0, max = 100, symbol = '%', gaugeSectors(
    success = c(80, 100), warning = c(40, 79), danger = c(0, 39)
  ))
})
```
````

**Here is my failed attempt:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
#library(flexdashboard)


ui <-dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    column(6,box(flexdashboard::gaugeOutput("plt1"),width=12,title="Gauge Graph",background ="green"))))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$plt1 <- flexdashboard::renderGauge({
      gauge(56, min = 0, max = 100, symbol = '%', label = paste("Test Label"),gaugeSectors(
        success = c(100, 6), warning = c(5,1), danger = c(0, 1), colors = c("#CC6699")
      ))

    })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: Your example is working for me

Comment: my bad! i forgot to remove `#` from `library(flexdashboard)`! Small mistake and actually long time to figure out!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the OP)*.

I forgot to remove `#` from `#library(flexdashboard)`, therefore the function `gauge` could not be find and gauge could not be rendered...